# How to delete an item from CDK drop List in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to implement a cdk Drag&Drop List. I have two components **Item-list** and **Item**. Below I have attached the code;

**item-list.component.html:**

```
<div>
<form [formGroup]="newTodoForm" class="flex mt-4">
<mat-form-field appearance="fill"
  ><input
    matInput
    placeholder="Add daily"
    formControlName="todoItem"
    (keyup.enter)="addTask()"
    autocomplete="off"
    #textInput
/></mat-form-field>
 </form>
</div>

<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<app-item
[value]="value"
*ngFor="let value of dailyList; index as i"
[type]="'DAILY'"
cdkDrag
>
</app-item>
</div>
```

**item.component.html:**

```
<div class="listContainer">

<div>
<mat-checkbox
  (change)="OnChange($event)"
  [checked]="IsChecked"
>
</mat-checkbox>
</div>

<div class="displayvalue" [ngClass]="{ 'line-through': value.Task }">
{{ value.Task | uppercase }}
</div>

<div>
<Matbutton mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</Matbutton>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon class="deleteitem" (click)="removeTask(value)"
      >delete</mat-icon
    >
    <span>remove</span>
   </button>
   </mat-menu>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a delete button in the above item component. so for every item created with a delete button. But when the button is triggered, it provides typeError on console.

**item.component.ts:**

```
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemType } from './item.data';

@Component({
selector: 'app-item',
templateUrl: './item.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./item.component.scss'],
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  [x: string]: any;

@Input() public type: ItemType = 'DAILY';
@Input()
 value: any;
IsChecked: boolean;

@Input() dailyList: any;

constructor() {
this.IsChecked = false;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
console.log('ItemComponent', this.type);
}

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
moveItemInArray(this['dailyList'], event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}

OnChange($event: any) {
if ($event.checked) console.log('the task is added');
else console.log('the task is removed');

}

removeTask(value:any){
value.splice(value,1);
}
}
```

In the above TS code, I have a function removeTask() created for the delete button. But it keep providing me typeError.

I would like to implement the function for this delete button, which removes the item from the itemlist.

I Would appreciate if someone could help me fix this issue

Comment: what kind of error come?

Comment: @Parth this is the error >   ERROR TypeError: value.splice is not a function

Comment: can you please put console.log in side removeTask method to console.log(value)

Comment: @Parth i did console.log(value) and it logs the value but the error is still in value.splice

Comment: can you please give stackbliz code snap to help you exactly what is problem with value. because this error occour only if value is not valid string input

Comment: @Parth when i log value inside remove task, it returns me this object > {Task: 'open the book'},

Comment: you are doing mistake in that method that you are trying to use split value from "Value" not from list of value

Comment: @Parth Can you show me how I can fix it., because the list of values are in the parent component item-list

Comment: you need to implement output parameter in remove method when you detete value then need to pass value back to parent component & in parent component need to split value.